# Curve color is dark grey instead of red on iPad. How to solve this?

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, chart.js, visualization

I want to make the kind of curve below but it does not work and Ipad.
The color appears grey.

Is it a bug of ChartJS or is there something we can do ?

I have this issue when type's value is "line".

It works on Ipad when type's value is "bar".

Do you have an idea of ways of dealing with this ?

[image: grey on Ipad]

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; margin-top:30px; height:60vh; width:90vh">
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from lists in backgroundColor and borderColor.

```
datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            borderWidth: 1
        }
```

Indeed, for kind equal to bar we can have one color for each label.

For the kind "line", seems that we can't have a list with only one value.

We only can have one color under the curve and one color for the border.